# positioning two elements to the right and one to the left using flex and align issue

Tags: html, css, css-position, text-alignment

I have an issue, regarding element positioning as well as text alignment:
the nav container has three elements: logo, title, nav-list.[codepen](https://codepen.io/noah314/pen/qBoBNVG?editors=1100)

```css
/**{
    
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        box-sizing: border-box;
    
    }*/

header {
  background-color: orange;
  url(../images/hero.jpg);
  height: 600px;
  background-size: cover;
}

.fixed-nav {
  list-style: none;
}

.fixed-nav li {
  display: inline-block;
}

nav {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  padding: 30px 40px;
}

.logo {
  height: 25px;
  width: 120px;
}

.title {
  color: white;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-family: "Avalors Personal Use", sans-serif;
}

.nav-menu {
  display: flex;
  gap: 1rem;
  /* text-align: center;*/
  list-style: none;
  justify-content: center;
  align-content: center;
}

.nav-menu li {
  font-family: "Avenir LT Std", sans-serif;
  display: inline-block;
  color: white;
  font-size: 16px;
}

.nav-menu li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
  /*padding-left:10px;
        padding-right:10px;*/
}
```

```html
<header>
  <ul class="fixed-nav">
    <li>phone</li>
    <li>whats</li>
    <li>search</li>
  </ul>
  <nav class="navbar">
    <a href="#" class="logo">
      <img src="#" alt="logo" />
    </a>
    <h2 class="title">
      title
    </h2>
    <ul class="nav-menu">
      <li> <a href="#">HOME</a> </li>
      <li> <a href="#">ABOUT</a> </li>
      <li> <a href="#">PRODUCTS</a> </li>
      <li> <a href="#">NEWS</a> </li>
      <li> <a href="#">CONTACT</a> </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
  <h2>Slogan</h2>
  <p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
  </p>
</header>
```

i couldn't figure out how to display logo and title to the left and the nav-list to the right.
when i use flex to display them horizontally the nav-list children show at the top-left corner. [demonstration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bvglv.png)
i tried: text-align, justify-content...with no results.
any insight is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

1. Make a wrapper for your title and logo.
2. Apply desired styles to the wrapper.

```
    <header>
  <ul class="fixed-nav">
    <li>phone</li>
    <li>whats</li>
    <li>search</li>
  </ul>
  <nav class="navbar">
    <div class='wrapper'>
      <a href="#" class="logo">
        <img src="#" alt="logo" />
      </a>
      <h2 class="title">
        title 
      </h2>
    </div>
    <ul class="nav-menu">
      <li> <a href="#">HOME</a> </li>
      <li> <a href="#">ABOUT</a> </li>
      <li> <a href="#">PRODUCTS</a> </li>
      <li> <a href="#">NEWS</a> </li>
      <li> <a href="#">CONTACT</a> </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
  <h2>Slogan</h2>
  <p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
  </p>
</header>
```

```
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
```

Comment: thanks for the suggestion the positioning issue is solved.
what about the alignment of nav-menu elements, if you hover over them in inspect mode, you will find them aligned to the top-left of the parent.

Comment: align-items: center should take care of that, paste a link to a jsfiddle or such if you still need help figuring it out

Answer (score 0):

Try This, It will work!

```css
/**{

    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;

}*/
header {
  background-color: orange;
    url(../images/hero.jpg);
  height: 600px;
  background-size: cover;
}
.fixed-nav {
  list-style: none;
}
.fixed-nav li {
  display: inline-block;
}
nav {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 30px 40px;
}
.logo {
  height: 25px;
}
.title {
  color: white;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-family: "Avalors Personal Use", sans-serif;
  margin-left: 10px;
}
.nav-menu {
  display: flex;
  gap: 1rem;
  /* text-align: center;*/
  list-style: none;
  justify-content: center;
  align-content: center;
}
.nav-menu li {
  font-family: "Avenir LT Std", sans-serif;
  display: inline-block;
  color: white;
  font-size: 16px;
}
.nav-menu li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
  /*padding-left:10px;
    padding-right:10px;*/
}
.demo {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <ul class="fixed-nav">
    <li>phone</li>
    <li>whats</li>
    <li>search</li>
  </ul>
  <nav class="navbar">
    <div class="demo">
    <a href="#" class="logo">
      <img src="#" alt="logo" />
    </a>
    <h2 class="title">
      title 
    </h2>
    </div>
    <ul class="nav-menu">
      <li> <a href="#">HOME</a> </li>
      <li> <a href="#">ABOUT</a> </li>
      <li> <a href="#">PRODUCTS</a> </li>
      <li> <a href="#">NEWS</a> </li>
      <li> <a href="#">CONTACT</a> </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
  <h2>Slogan</h2>
  <p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
  </p>
</header>
```

Comment: thank you, so you solved the alignment issue using : justify-content and align content, right?

Comment: Yes, It is for alignment.

Answer (score 0):

```
.nav-menu {
  margin-left: auto;
}
```

Comment: thank you, this is for positioning issue,
what about the alignment problem: if you hover over the nav-list in inspect mode you find that the element are on top-left not centered